# Calculate average per row and then calculate average per column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table shown below

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
NULL    NULL    NULL    54.84
NULL    NULL    NULL    75.40
57.24   73.61   NULL    NULL
```

I want to first calculate the average of the row and then calculate the final average of the column

So my calculation becomes

```
    Row1Avg   54.84
    Row2Avg   75.40
    Row3Avg   65.42
```

And then I arrive at the final average of `Row1Avg,Row2Avg,Row3Avg  = 65.22`

Can some please tell me how to achieve this in an efficient manner. How I was thinking of doing it is I have a temp table with single column where I store the AVG of the rows and then I just take average of the temp table column. Was just wondering if there might be a better way of doing it.

Comment: So if column is NULL you don't want to add it to the average calculation?

Comment: Yeah I don't want that.

Comment: I think your calculation is wrong for `Row3Avg`. That is not the average, but the sum.

Comment: Sorry updated the post.

Comment: Can't you just pivot the table and then use the `AVG()` function?

Comment: Can you please show me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `cross apply` and `grouping sets`:

```
select t.id, avg(row_avg)
from t cross apply
     (select avg(col) as row_avg
      from (values (col1), (col2), (col3), (col4)) v(col)
     ) s
group by grouping sets ( (id), () );
```

The above assumes that you have a unique id to identify each row.  If not, then you need something like `union all`:

```
with s as (
      select t.*, s.row_avg
      from t cross apply
           (select avg(col) as row_avg
            from (values (col1), (col2), (col3), (col4)) v(col)
           ) s
     )
select s.row_avg
from s
union all
select avg(s.row_avg)
from s;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon..Didn't had a unique id so your second approach seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try with CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT 
    AVG(t2.Average)
FROM
    Table t1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT Average = AVG(Value) 
        FROM (VALUES (Col1), (Col2), (Col3), (Col4)) B1(Value)
    ) t2
```

Result is `65.221666`

Answer (score 0):

So you need both average for each row and each column? I would do two separate calculations, one for row and another for column. Read through the table and find the average for each row, store the column values in a temp column tables or lists.